# WPF MVVM auto GUI test - Code coverage

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, code-coverage, autotest

Thanks to a full WPF MVVM design, I managed to record all commands and view events (throw view model, like selected objects, shown objects ids, ...) in XML files during manual scenarii testing.
Then it's easy to replay the recorded scenari :)

It works fine and permits to quickly check most of my code - I'm proud of it and so excited about .Net ! ;o)

But, how could I check my code coverage ?

I'm not using in this case Unit Testing, just running the app in Debug mode **but I'd like to know which code is tested/untested.**

Any idea ?

Thanks,
Nd

Comment: Something like this? See the section about **Manual coverage**: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/2016.1/Getting_Started_with_dotCover.html

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I'm didn't know this feature of Resharper (Ultimate version only). I'll have a look, but I'm not sure to be able to get it paid by my boss :) I'll try if I don't find a free way to see my code coverage.

Comment: Hi Haukinger, I tested DotCover, it's very simple to use and efficient. I didn't got another free way to cover my code so I'll try to buy it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a great article thanks to a friend at code project :

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/590346/codepluscoverageplusforplusregressionplustestsplus

Thanks to snehal harawande for its great article on scenarii testing for FREE. I did use .Net 4.5.2 64 bits (Add "x64" on first batch line argument) and I did import the result in VS Enterprise. It's perfect :)

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework`, then modify your `App.xaml.cs` as follows:

```
+using System.Reflection ;
+using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting ;

 namespace YourAppNamespace
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// Interaction logic for App.xaml.
     /// </summary>
+    [TestClass]
     public partial class App
     {
+        [TestMethod]
+        public void Test ()
+        {
+            ResourceAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly () ;
+            InitializeComponent () ;
+            Run () ;
+        }
     }
 }
```

Now you can use Visual Studio's built-in test runner and code coverage instrumentation: instead of "Debug/Start Debugging" use "Test/Analyze Code Coverage/All Tests". (The console test runner `vstest.console.exe` doesn't work, though.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform code coverage on a live test, i.e. not a set of unit tests, then you can create one unit test that actually fires up the live code (e.g. make a call in to main or however your program runs up), perform your test scenarios, and then end the program.  At that point the unit testing framework (and I'd recommend dotCover as stated by Haukinger) will see the test has come to an end, and it will have picked up the code coverage information for you.

Comment: Hi, I'm gonna have a look again, but until now the result is not fantastic :). The view doesn't really show; it only flashes at start and I can't see it again. If my view fon't show, I will have no rendering and I need to test it :(. Itried it on an empty project and tried to launch in another Thread while UT is sleeping,  not better. Do I miss something ?